# Laravel response stream to download a CSV file is not returning the specified headers in the response

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I am trying to generate a CSV file on the-fly inside of Laravel. I set up some basic things in my constructor:

```
$this->stream = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$this->fileName = $this->fileName = sprintf('Asset_Register_%s.csv', Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y'));
```

My route executes the following function code:

```
fputcsv($this->stream, [
    'some', 'headers', 'to', 'display'
]);

return response()->stream(callback: fn() => $this->generateExport(), headers: [
    'Content-type' => "text/csv",
    'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename={$this->fileName}",
    'Pragma' => "no-cache",
    'Cache-Control' => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
    'Expires' => "0"
]);
```

The `generateExport` simply loops through a database collection and puts it into the stream like, ie:

```
$response = collect([
    ['some' => 1, 'headers' => 2, 'to' => 3, 'display' => 4],
    ['some' => 4, 'headers' => 5, 'to' => 6, 'display' => 7]
]);

foreach ($response as $row)
{
    fputcsv($this->stream, $row->toArray());
}
```

Now the problem I have is that none of the specified response headers are present in the response thus meaning the file is displayed as `text/html` as apposed to being automatically downloaded into a CSV file.

[image: Request/Response Headers]

Any help here would be appreciated, I'm using Firefox and am directly visiting the route in the browser.

Comment: But is content actual CSV returned? Maybe you get handled error instead? I don't really see where your `generateExport` returns any of the content.

Comment: You could always download it like this `return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);` or you can just streamDownload https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#streamed-downloads and if you are worried about saving the files, you can always call `->deleteFileAfterSend(true);`

Comment: Hi @Justinas the browser displays all of my content and I don't see any errors even with debug mode enabled. I have just also `tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log` and hit refresh a few times with nothing written to it

Comment: Hi @KGG I don't really want to even have to write to a file, seems uncessarry, this normally works perfectly fine other than in this case where I cannot see the expected headers in the response

Comment: @KGG as a quick solution, I implented your example: 1. `Storage::disk('local')->put(sprintf('%s-%s.csv', auth()->user()->id, ($this->time = time())), '');` 2. Point the `fopen` stream to this file and write with `fputs` 3. Download the file and delete it after send - many thanks, feel free to write an answer i can accept

Comment: @Jaquarh I appreciate that, I'm just glad that something worked out for you and that you are happy with the results. I prefer that you write that answer as you are the one that put the work and effort into fixing it on your own, just needed a little direction :) best of luck